# Execute at the end of tablesorter function?

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I tried to create a code to execute something at the end of a tablesorter function, however I made a mistake somewhere.

*Here's the original:*

```
$("#myTable").tablesorter({  
        headers: {  
            0: { 
                sorter: false 
            }
        },
        widgets: ['zebra']


    });
```

*Here's my addition:*

```
$("#myTable").tablesorter({  
        headers: {  
            0: { 
                sorter: false 
            }
        },
        widgets: ['zebra'],
        function() {
        //execute something
        }); 


    });
```

*And here's my error:*

> missing : after property id function() {

Thanks for looking over my question everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a sortEnd event, like this sample:

```
$("#myTable").bind("sortEnd",function() {
    //execute something
});
```

See here for more details: http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-triggers.html

Comment: Hi Sergio, thanks but that code doesn't execute. I think that it only works if you're actually sorting the tables with mouse clicks, not when tablesorter loads.

Comment: Hi pufAmuf, reviewing your code, the is a aditional ';' in the line 9. Maybe this is generating the error you described. I'm not sure if your callback will work, the method I described is that I know and the method in the documentation of tablesorted.

Comment: The "sortEnd" does fire when the table is resorted, so it won't fire at all during startup unless you have the `sortList` option set to sort. Use Sergio's method and remove the `function(){ });` from inside of the options and it should start working.